# what does the condition in the following if statement do?

Tags: c++

```
if (read(read(cin, data1), data2))
```

The question is a exercise of *C++ Primer 5th Edition*. The function `read` is define like following:

```
std::istream &read(std::istream &is, Sales_data &item)
{
    double price = 0;
    is >> item.bookNo >> item.units_sold >> price;
    item.revenue = price * item.units_sold;
    return is;
}
```

What does the condition in the if statement do? I can't understand this point.

Comment: Exercise! So, what's the point if we solve it for you while you can read the book again?

Comment: @MM. I just can't understand the `condition` mean. What is the question really asking? I should input two Sales_data items? and then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the condition in the if statement do? I can't understand
>   this point.

You shouldn't ask for solutions of exercises; That diminishes the learning effect. Go through the chapter and the function again and see if you can spot important points.

Perhaps it helps if you write it out a little bit differently:

```
   std::istream& a = read(cin, data1);
   std::istream& b = read(a  , data2);
   if (b)
        // ...
```

Comment: Sorry for asking the solutions of exercises... and thx your clearly division. I get it.

Answer (score 1):

The `read` function returns the input stream, it's similar to a common usage:

```
int v1, v2;
if (std::cin >> v1 >> v2)
//...
```

I guess at this stage of the book, operator overloading is not introduced yet, it would be more clear if the operator `<<` is overloaded for the class `Sales_data`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `read`, in this case, takes a `std::istream` object reference and returns the same type. This is done so that `read` can be called cascaded. Consider:

```
cin >> a >> b;
```

How do you think `a >> b` is supposed to work? It is just that `cin.operator>>(int&)` returns the  `cin` object itself. Hence, by understanding, `read` is following same approach.